# Does anything happen if I light all the lanterns with blue flame?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Breath of the Wild, there are two "Tech Labs". Upon arriving, both give you a mini-quest to light the furnace outside the lab with a "blue flame".

Along the path, when carrying the lit torch, there are stone lanterns you can light with the blue flame (presumably as a "checkpoint" for when it may start to rain).

Do these lanterns serve any other purpose? I.e. will anything happen if I light them all, as some puzzles did in older Zelda games?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, they do nothing once you light them, but they do stay lit forever in case you are near one and ever need to start a fire for some reason.

There is also a small mini-game involving lighting a blue torch and its easier if there happens to be a nearby torch that is already lit.

Comment: There is also a [mini-game](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Blue_Flame/) involving lighting the lanterns with blue flames

Comment: @Wondercricket that was the small quest I was referring to but I guess it should be called mini game since its repeatable

Answer (score 1):

While no, using the blue flame to light all the torches doesn't do anything, the blue flame itself does have other purposes:

These include:

- Unique interactions with NPCs around the village(s) and getting children to follow you
- Detonating Bombs
- Destroying Ice Pillars